# What is the right way to elevate props in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I apologize if my phrasing is wrong in the title. I've recently gotten cookies going in my app. My Topnav component needs access to them, but I'm unsure how to get them there.

App.js -

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Landing from './pages/Landing.js';
import LoginPage from './pages/LoginPage.js';
import Topnav from './pages/components/global/Topnav.js';
import './Global.css';

const App = props => (
  <div>
    <Topnav />
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/'      component={Landing} />
      <Route exact path='/login' component={LoginPage} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

My login component grabs the cookie from express (fetch) and then does a `<Redirect to='/' />`
This loads up my Landing page, where I'm able to grab the cookie, but how do I get the cookie to the Topnav? I saw an answer to something like this on stack where it seems like App.js grabs the cookie and passes it as a props to the components, but I don't see how it could if it never refreshes. I've thought about forcing an entire window refresh (which does work for Topnav when I do a refresh manually), but I've also seen answers here that say don't do that.

Comment: I'm going with context here. This video series and particularly this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CGRpfIUURE0 really helped set in how to use contexts, if anyone else is struggling with this. Thanks again, Joe Lloyd, for the direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use Context

You need to use the new context hook from react.

### Create a context

This is a context that you can access around your app.

`const MyContext = React.createContext(defaultValue);`

### Make a provider

Wrap the provider around your main app

`<MyContext.Provider value={/* some value */}>`

### Access the context at the point at which you get the cookies

Use this in both your login and top nav to use the value from the context

`const value = useContext(MyContext);`

Comment: I see! Thank you. I've used context with socket.io so I should've thought of this. Cheers!

Comment: to be honest this is the easy level approach since the context api is already available in react and requires no setup. But if you need to do some more things like this consider using redux. It also uses hooks now but has much easier ways of getting and changing data from anywhere in your app.

Comment: I'm building a portfolio because I'd like to make this a career. I've seen that most ads on indeed want Redux experience, but I figured it'd be good to know how to work with basic React before jumping into deeper libraries. Would you say it'd be better for me to go ahead and jump into Redux? I honestly haven't looked much into it. I have been a little confused about using multiple contexts. Sounds like Redux simplifies this.

Comment: i wouldn't say it more simple, people actually find the amount of boilerplate in redux to be to complex. I would say stick to react as is and learn them hooks.

Comment: Thanks again, Joe. I'll stick to React as is for this project and watch some videos on Redux soon to get a feel for what it is. I'm really curious now.

Comment: awesome. try it with hooks. you also need the lib `react-redux` when you start

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to approach this.

Probably a beginner friendly one.

When your login Component does the login successfully you need to signal to the `App` Component about it probably using a `onLoginSuccessful` which can then read the cookie and do a `setState` with it and use this component state value in the props to your `Topnav` and `Landing` Component